# “Hidden fish”: old riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, language

```
There are six fish on these lines. Can you name them?
Here are the ten chains you wished.
She had lost her ring and was looking for it.
He met Carol in Geneva.
That rout was very complete.
I saw him scamper cheerfully away.
Make Ella give it to her mother.
```

---

*Source (this is not intended to be used to look up the answer, but is posted under [the policy on plagiarism of the Puzzle Stack Exchange website](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism)):*

> Source: The Queenslander (discontinued in 1939), without any specific author.

Comment: *Where* was it presented in 1919?

Comment: You should post the source. Otherwise, there is no originality of the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are:

> tench: "Here are the **ten ch**ains you wished."
>  herring: "She had lost **her ring** and was looking for it."
>  ling: "He met Caro**l in G**eneva."
>  trout: "Tha**t rout** was very complete."
>  perch: "I saw him scam**per ch**eerfully away."
>  eel: "Mak**e El**la give it to her mother."